# How to show progressbar in App store during installation?

Tags: mac-appstore, install

I try to install Xcode through App store. As I found, it can take a long time (hours) while it is fully installed. Is it possible to display progressbar, how much time (estimately) is remaining to finish installation? Or at least a progress bar, that shows, how much percent of size was downloaded / installed? 
[image: Screenshot of my App store window, which says, that Xcode is installing]

Answer (score 4):

There should be a progress bar underneath the Launchpad dock icon.

If you removed Launchpad from your dock, open it through Spotlight, then search for the icon of the app you are installing (which in your case would be Xcode). There should be a progress bar and further status information on it.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the « Purchased » tab of the Mac App Store. There will be a progress bar.